# Pygame cursor in for loop only working on last

Tags: python, for-loop, pygame, cursor

I'm trying to switch the cursor in pygame (python module) when the mouse is around rects stored in list and then the mouse get back to normal.

I tested the loop, its working in many ways. But with a switch on cursor, only on the last element of the list is working(the indentation is ok). It's quite weird, i have tested many things but it doesn't work.

Here is my code :

```
pygame.init()

[...]

button = pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (585, 424, 50, 50))
button2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (235, 274, 30, 30))
button3 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (440, 311, 40, 40))
all_buttons = [button2, button3, button]

running = True
while running:

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    for x in all_buttons:
        if x.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*pygame.cursors.diamond)

        else:
            pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*pygame.cursors.arrow)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

I also tested this :

```
 def mouse_state(cursor_state):
    if cursor_state:
        pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*pygame.cursors.arrow)
    else:
        pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*pygame.cursors.diamond)
```

[...]

```
cursor_state = True
while running:
    for x in all_buttons:
        if x.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            cursor_state = False
        else:
            cursor_state = True

    mouse_state(cursor_state)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're constantly setting the cursor back to arrow when the cursor is not in the *next* box.

Walk through your algorithm:

- if cursor in box1

  - set cursor to diamond
- else

  - set cursor to arrow
- if cursor in box2

  - set cursor to diamond
- else

  - set cursor to arrow
- if cursor in box3

  - set cursor to diamond
- else

  - set cursor to arrow

So unless you're hovering over the last box, the cursor is only set to diamond for a split-second, before being re-set in the next box-test.  Probably you never see it change when over the first 2 boxes.

One way around is to set a flag when the mouse is inside *any* box, then use that flag to set the mouse-cursor.

Comment: Ow.. Very interesting, didn't see that in this way ! Thank you ! So now, i'm still looking for a way to switch this cursor when mouse position is in thoses box (there will have many). Didn't find a solution for now

Comment: Thank you for your time. Your idea is working very well !